# How can i write HQL statements inside criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a case where i need to use a sub-select join inside my criteria. Normal FetchMode.JOIN (as given below) doesn't work, as the database is old and mappings are messed up. Is there way to use SQL inside my criteria to join the tables.

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
List users = criteria.list() {
    fetchMode "comments", FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode "comments.property", FetchMode.JOIN
}
```

Comment: How does the domain class `User` look like?

Comment: Thanks dmahapatro.. The actual domain modal is a bit complex. Usually, what i wrote, works fine. But, in this case the associations are all wrong in the database and sql is what i need. Is there way to use SQL inside my criteria to join the tables? like sqlRestrictions, but for join statements!

Comment: Then why don't use HQL query instead of criteria? Ultimately criteria is going to be converted to an HQL query and then executed. Using `executeQuery` would give more flexibility for joins.

Comment: Am using a reusable criteria builder, which is quite customizable. There are lots of combination of search conditions and criteria using is the best solution, for re-usability and readability. If nothing works i will have rewrite every logic using HQL. Is it not  impossible to write HQL/SQL together with criteria?

Comment: I don't think so. I would rather try if DetachedCriteria can be used instead of trying to mix and match with SQL and criteria or would totally shift towards HQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
List users = criteria.list() { //or User.withCriteria
    comments {
        property {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

should do with what you are trying to. Skeptical about the usage as `property` for the association, otherwise I would try for `"property" { }`.